# netmsmqbinding with silverlight connections limit

Tags: wcf, silverlight, msmqbinding

I have develop a silverlight chat application. my question is (a) can netmsmqbinding support unlimited connections of wcf service. because first im use pollingduplex binding but it support only 10 connection on iis6 also on server edition.im allready set service throttling options but not effect on server iis. so that now i want to go for netmsmqbinding. please explain me **msmqbinding** limitations.can  its better for chat application or not?

help me for take decision.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (but I don't know Silverlight all that well), it supports only the basicHttpBinding.

And even if Silverlight did support MSMQ - this is definitely not a good protocol to use when you're creating a chat application. The queue can buffer messages and deliver them later. That works well in many scenarios, but when I chat with someone, I want my message to show up right away - not "some time later".....

So if you really need to use MSMQ in some way, I think you'd have to have a BasicHttp-based front-end service that goes from your Silverlight client to the server, and then on the server actually route your message forward to a MSMQ queue.

Marc

Comment: Also MSMQ would be a required component for the client, which is not installed by default and would limit you to Windows only clients.